# What are bash packages?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

The [Google bash style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=Function_Names#Function_Names) mentions bash packages, where the package name should be separated from the function name by double colons

> If you're writing single functions, use lowercase and separate words with underscore. If you're writing a package, separate package names with ::. Braces must be on the same line as the function name (as with other languages at Google) and no space between the function name and the parenthesis.

```
# Single function
my_func() {
  ...
}

# Part of a package
mypackage::my_func() {
  ...
}
```

I've googled but found no references to bash packages except for the [Lightweight bash Package Manager](https://github.com/bpkg/bpkg).  Is that what they're referring to?

Comment: Look like just another way of introducing "namespaces".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that Bash has any built-in support for packages in the way that "real" programming languages do. It's probably just a naming convention used to mimic [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) for the purposes of code organization. See the following post for further discussion:

- [What are double colons :: in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558080/what-are-double-colons-in-a-shell-script)

I imagine it was inspired by the syntax used for [Perl modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_module).

Comment: As if you put a bunch of functions in `mylib.sh` all being prefixed with `mylib::` and then source that file at the top of your "end user" scripts. IOW, home-rolled namespaces?

Comment: @RonJohn Yeah, that's my take-away.